# Как правильно подключить файлы .hpp?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, объявление

В файле B.hpp выдает ошибку "Unknown type name 'F'", хотя файл с объявлением F подключен. В чем проблема?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Game.hpp"

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Game.hpp

```
#ifndef Game_hpp
#define Game_hpp

#include <stdio.h>

#include "F.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"

class Game {
    F * a;
    B * b;
};

#endif /* Game_hpp */
```

IObserver.hpp

```
#ifndef IObserver_hpp
#define IObserver_hpp

#include <stdio.h>

class IObserver {

};

#endif /* IObserver_hpp */
```

B.hpp

```
#ifndef B_hpp
#define B_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include "IObserver.hpp"
#include "F.hpp"

class B: public IObserver {

public:

    void funB (F * a);
};

#endif /* B_hpp */
```

Base.cpp

```
#include "B.hpp"

void B::funB (F * a){}
```

C.hpp

```
#ifndef C_hpp
#define C_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include "B.hpp"

class C {
    B * a;
};

#endif /* C_hpp */
```

F.hpp

```
#ifndef F_hpp
#define F_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include "C.hpp"

class F {
    C * a;
};

#endif /* F_hpp */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну смотрите сами...

`Game.hpp` включает `F.hpp` который включает `С.hpp`, который...

Словом, если вы просто внесете содержимое каждого hpp-файла вместо строки с `#include`, то получите вот такое начало:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
class B: public IObserver {

public:

    void funB (F * a);
};

class C {
    B * a;
};

class F {
    C * a;
};
```

Просто в момент объявления `void funB (F * a);` компилятор ничего не знает ни о каком `F`, вот и все.

Таким большим количеством архисложнопереплетенных :) заголовочных файлов вы запутываете сами себя...

Не знаю, что у вас за компилятор, но если посмотреть на результат работы препроцессора (в VC++ - ключ /EP), то увидим следующее:

```
class IObserver {
};
class B: public IObserver {
public:
    void funB (F * a);
};
class C {
    B * a;
};
class F {
    C * a;
};
class Game {
    F * a;
    B * b;
};
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а как можно избежать данную ситуацию, вместо include объявлять class "Name";?

Comment: У вас есть циклическая зависимость классов - B зависит от F, F - от C, С - от B, и в каком именно месте вы ее разорвете - в общем-то, все равно. Можете для С объявить `class B;`, можете для B - `class F;`, можете для F - `class C;` - это уже смотрите сами...